# Change border color of QWidget using animation

Tags: c++, qt

I have tried to change border color of Qwidget for two days but Doesn't work.

so I refered to another code which is posted on the stackoverflow about moving widget. it worked perpectly but I can't change border color using QPropertyAnimation. give some tips for this problem.

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui.defectView, "border-color");
animation->setDuration(2000);
animation->setStartValue(QColor(0, 0, 0));
animation->setEndValue(QColor(240, 240, 240));
animation->start();
```

Comment: What type of widget is defectView?

Comment: It is QWidget. I just named it defecrView.

Answer (score 1):

There is no QWidget property called "border-color". All it's properties are shown in QWidget documentation. But you can change this color using QSS and animate it. Also consider custom paintEvent depending on your needs.

Comment: Yes. Look of Qt widgets usualy can be changed in several ways, including:

    1. reimplement `paintEvent`
    2.`QWidget::setPalette(const QPalette &)`
    3.`QWidget::setStyle(QStyle *style)` and `QApplication::setStyle`
    4.`setStyleSheet(const QString &styleSheet)`
    5. any combination of them

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation I will try to use it.